# How to convert image in form of RGB (2-D matrix)

Tags: matlab, k-means, imread

I have an image of size 128x128. I have applied imread function of matlab on it,
A= imread(first.jpg);
but this is returning me a 3-D array 128x128x3 , how can I convert it to a 2-D matrix consisting of 3 columns R, G, B (one column for each color)?

Comment: Do you want to obtain a matrix  thas has 3 columns and 16384 (128^2) rows, that is one rows per pixel?

Comment: yes, I want RGB value of each pixel in a row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
A = imread('first.jpg');
Npixels = size(A,1)*size(A,2);
newA = reshape(A,[Npixels,3]);
```

Comment: thanks. it's working absolutely fine, can you also tell me how can I convert this back to jpg image?

Comment: @Tehreem Fatima To get back to the original size you will need to save the image size after loading it `Asz = size(A);`. Then perform a reshape operation after processing `origA = reshape(newA, Asz);`

Comment: yes, what jodag wrote is correct, if you wish to save it `imwrite(origA,'newImage.jpg','jpg');` @TehreemFatima